# Ordered orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

As we know matrix is normal if $AA^*=A^*A$ . In book statement is if $T$ is a linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space $V$ is normal if and only if for any ordered orthonormal basis $B$, matrix representation of $T$ with respect to this basis $B$ is normal matrix.

My question, Is here required $B$ is an orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $B$ a transfer matrix from the standard basis to the new basis $B$. If $B$ is not orthonormal, then this happens:

$$(BTB^{-1})(BTB^{-1})^\ast\overset{?}{=}(BTB^{-1})^\ast(BTB^{-1})$$
$$BT(B^{-1}B^{\ast-1})T^\ast B^\ast\overset{?}{=}B^{\ast-1} T^\ast (B^\ast B) TB^{-1}$$
By inspection, you require that $B^\ast=B^{-1}$ otherwise left and right side cannot be the same. This is why orthonormal basis is needed.